# Electric Field for a conducting infinite plane formula contradiction

Tags: electromagnetism, gauss-law

We know the electric field of an infinite plane is $\frac{N}{2e_0}$, where N is the charge density, but for conducting objects its $\frac{N}{e_0}$?

This is a contradiction. Or because the plane is infinite, the conductor  formula fails to work? Or do conductors need volume

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A conductor must consist of a union of surfaces and bulk. Therefore, a conducting sheet must have two sides separated by a neutral bulk(However thin that might be). Therefore, within a given volume of an insulating sheet and a conducting sheet, the latter has twice the amount of charge and produces twice the electric field twice.